# Question 3.4 from Brezis' book of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

**Question:** Let E be a Banach space and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $E$ such that $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in the weak topology $\sigma(E, E')$. Prove that there exists a sequence $(z_n) \in E$ such that

1. $z_n \in \text{conv}\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\{x_i\}\right)\; \forall n$, and
2. $z_n\longrightarrow x$ strongly.

I'm strugglin to prove this question, I guess I'm misunderstanding some new concepts in the weak topology. But, I've reviwed in the Brezis'Book, and I still in doubt. Would someone give a hint here?

Comment: This result is sometimes called Mazur's lemma.  Does this answer your question? [Mazur's Lemma (can't find a proof anywhere)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116488/mazurs-lemma-cant-find-a-proof-anywhere)

Comment: Yes, you're right! I did not know that there was that name "Mazur's Lemma". Thanks for the information.